# Where does OS X store unsaved TextEdit documents?

Tags: macos, text-editor, textedit

Where does Mac OS X store TextEdit's unsaved documents?

I want to programmatically:

1. increase/decrease that size
2. flush the cache
3. provide configuration option to control the frequency of auto saving/caching

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do #1: the mechanisms available for OS X and TextEdit to keep the unsaved documents don't depend on a static size; the storage space will grow or shrink as needed.

Comment: what do you mean by static size ? i am keenly interested to locate the place where OSX keeps these unsaved files from the TextEdit.

Comment: "Static" as in "unchanging". There's nothing saying "this file will be X megabytes" anywhere: it's allowed to float to be as big as it needs to be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Lion: It is in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Autosave\ Information/`, e.g. `Unsaved TextEdit Document.rtf`.

Note that ~/Library is not visible by default in Finder in Lion, but you can access it by pasting the path in Finder (without the backslash in "Autosave Information"; the formatting above is for cd-ing in Terminal.app), or there is an option to enable the visibility (`chflags nohidden ~/Library`)

For Snow Leopard (credit goes to @binarybob, his comment is below) it is in `~/Library/Autosave Information` also named `Unsaved TextEdit Document.rtf`

Comment: Thanks for the response . I do'nt have a containers folder ? where else can i look ?

Comment: Which OS X version are you using? Are you sure that you are looking in `~/Library` and not `/Library`? Finally, try to create unsaved document in Text Edit, and see if the directory appears; it may not be there by default.

Comment: @JayD On Lion, its in the path as @lupincho states. On Snow Leopard, it appears in `~/Library/Autosave Information` also named `Unsaved TextEdit Document.rtf`

Comment: @binarybob thanks for the OS flavor specific location. Had you written an answer, i would chosen it. :-)

Comment: @JayD Thanks, but the existing answer already provided correct information, all I did was augment it :) If lupincho wants to add my comment to the actual answer, I'm more than happy for that to happen.

Comment: @binarybob: I added your comment to the answer.

Comment: What about Mavericks ?

Comment: **Be careful, TextEdit forgets to resume some documents.** In Mavericks, I look in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Autosave Information`, and what a surprise ! I find about 40 documents stored. In TextEdit I have only 13 documents. In resuming the sessions, week after week, TextEdit has lost many other documents — I have not closed them. The good news is that these documents did not get deleted. The bad news is that TextEdit forgot to restore many of these documents.

Comment: **Be careful, in Mavericks, TextEdit forgets to save and restore RTF documents.**

Answer (score 4):

Note: For macOS Mavericks, the path is slightly different. It's `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Documents`.